# ENTITIES matching conflicting in LUIS

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, azure-language-understanding

I have two entities created in LUIS. One entity to identify the AlphaNumeric word and another one to identify a word with a pattern. Both entities are created using a regular expression.

To identify alphanumeric I used - **\w+\d+** regular expression.

To identify the word with a pattern I used - **^venid\d+** (words like venid12345, venid32310...)

These two entities are mapped to two different INTENTS. But actually how much I trained the LUIS, still the first entity is only getting recognized. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the regex entities from Entities tab and train the app, then add utterances from the intents tab for the respective intent. This should enable the model to pickup the regex entities irrespective of the mapping. Here is a screen shot of both these entities getting recognized for some alphanumeric patterns.

[image]

**numericalpha** is the first pattern and **vendor** is the second pattern that i have added in the LUIS app.